# arabic regex and MySQLdb in python

Tags: python, unicode, base64, arabic, mysql-python

I've tried to get certain Arabic string from web page then store these strings into db.

**The first problem**

The only way I could is to specify how many letters are they by using `.` and use unicode, like this:

```
import urllib,re
content=urllib.urlopen("http://example.com/content.html").read()
content = unicode(content,"utf-8")
Strings = re.findall("<Strong>...........</strong>",content) # it will work fine and fetch it but only strings with 11 char or letter (11 place)
```

**Second problem**

When I tried to write it to text file it displays:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)

And when I've tried to store it into database it displays:

> ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd9\x82\xd8\xb5\xd9\x8a\xd8\xb1)' at line 1")

What I've think about is to fetch it then encode it into base64 then store it into db 
but still got an error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 1):

> The only way I could is to specify how many letters are they by using . and use unicode, like this

OK... is that a problem? Other than the general unreliability of hacking strings out of HTML with regex, obviously - consider using a proper parser (eg lxml.html et al).

> When I tried to write it to text file it displays: UnicodeEncodeError

Files are bytes, so to write to a text file you have to encode the characters back to bytes. eg

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(content.encode('utf-8'))
```

if you try to write characters directly, Python will guess an encoding, typically ASCII, which will then fail as above because Arabic is not representable in ASCII.

> And when I've tried to store it into database it displays: ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd9\x82\xd8\xb5\xd9\x8a\xd8\xb1)'

Post code? I don't think that's a Unicode problem. It looks more like you were creating a query with the content in it, without surrounding that content with quotes. Don't do that - use parameterised queries.

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO something VALUES ('+content+')')     # fails, and security horror
c.execute('INSERT INTO something VALUES (%s)', (content,))  # fine
```

> What I've think about is to fetch it then encode it into base64

Again, base64 operates on bytes, not characters, so encode first.

```
content.encode('utf-8').encode('base64')
```

but you shouldn't have to encode to base64 to store Unicode characters in a database. Ensure you are using table columns with a UTF-8 collation, and use UTF-8 as the connection charset, and no extra processing should be necessary.